# Does contentful java skd closes body from okhttp?

Tags: okhttp, contentful

I am using contentful java sdk.
I am fetching asynchronously(with callback) all content types.
After a brief moment I receive a warning:

> WARNING: A connection to https://cdn.contentful.com/ was leaked. Did you forget to close a response body?

I couldn't find a way to fix it. Is there any support from contentful sdk for it?
How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It occurs contentful java sdk didn't close body in case of an exception. They fixed it recently.

Answer (score 1):

looks like the problem is related to https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/2311. Most likely, you need to use try/finally with body.close() in the finally block. If the issue still remains, please share your code sample.

Comment: Yup it was related. I couldn't do that, cause the connection was done by contentful java sdk, and it didn't let me close the body. I was trying to do so, but I couldn't.